# Running Monkeyrunner over WIFi and also as an application

Tags: android, monkeyrunner

I have an android application which sends screenshots to other Android device.
Now I want to control the first android device from second one.I will send the touch co-ordinates and touch type.

As a solution I will run monkeyrunner code on first device which sends screenshots.

My question is Can I run monkeyrunner code as part of Android application which will start when I launch the screenshot application.

Second question, Can monkeyrunner work over WIFI.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to run `monkeyrunner` on a device, but why do you need it after all to do what you mentioned.

Yes. `monkeyrunner` can run over wifi as long as you setup `adb` to run over wifi.